# Angular Build reverse engineering: How to revert minified javascript files to their original typescript form

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, webpack, source-maps

I have a series of js files. (i.e. 0.js , 1.js, 2.js, 3.js ... 15.js) along with 0.js.map , 1.js.map ... 15.js.map in a folder that also contains main.js and main.js.map and vendor.js along with vendor.js.map.

These are files that contain Phonegap(Cordova) and Ionic code.

The project is probably using Angular for building. Although in the Chrome Dev Tools in the Sources tab I can only see the ng folder. A webpack folder does not seem to be displayed. According to https://angular.io/cli/build :

> The application builder uses the webpack build tool, with default configuration options specified in the workspace configuration file (angular.json) or with a named alternative configuration.

[image]

Is there a way to convert the files in their original Typescript format using the source map files (.js.map) in order to alter them?

Comment: If I understood correctly, before serving, make sure you build with source maps option:
 
`npm run build --source-map` or `ionic build --source-map`